# GetMessage() take excessive long time MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

When I call

```
var result = MailKit.GetMessage(uid)
```

Then the call takes around 4 seconds to return. Is there any better/faster way to get the mime message from the server??
Currently doing the following:
**1.** Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags)
**2.** Loop the fetch result to find a messageId match
**3.** Send GetMessage() with the UID found previously.

I can see that FETCH in most cases takes around 2 secs, all in all my process will take something like 6 seconds, which is kinda "long" before I can present the email in the client.

Is there a faster way to get a mime message from a mail server using MailKit, when all I know about the email is the `MessageID`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache all of the message summaries so that you don't have to ask the server for them each time...

You could also try:

```
var uids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("Message-Id", messageId));
if (uids.Count > 0)
    message = folder.GetMessage (uids[0]);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the text/html content only?? Then I could skip emails which have attachments, and show the content text asap for the users.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the samples in the MailKit github repo: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Comment: In the sample you're storing Body which is a BodyPart type. What I want is the html and text parts of the mime, but without the attachment in order to get the message faster from the server, or if I choose to cache the mails in memory (of cause it isn't possible to cache attachments of emails in memory...). Any specific point where I can find this in the example? As far as I can see, I can't get html and text contents from a BodyPart type, or did I miss anything?

Comment: You're missing something ;-) BodyPart is an abstract type. If the body part is a BodyPartText, then it is a text part. You can traverse the BodyPart's to find the BodyPartText that you want and then call ImapFolder.GetBodyPart() with the BodyPart you want and get the text or html that the BodyPart contains.